# Render text in foreground

Tags: c++, opengl, text, graphics, glut

I am trying to render some strings in the foreground in a OpenGL/GLUT application under MacOSX 10.7.2.

At the moment I am using this code to draw a few lines in the foreground and it works fine.

```
void drawForeground() {

int width = 10;
int height = 10;

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                    
glPushMatrix(); 
glLoadIdentity();                           
glOrtho(-1, width, -1, height, -1, 1);      
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);         

glPushMatrix(); 
glLoadIdentity();

glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);          

glBegin(GL_LINES);
//Draw the lines
glEnd();

/*********************/

glPopMatrix();      
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                    
glPopMatrix();  
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);   

}
```

Now I would like to draw also some text. In the previous function I added this piece of code in the line where I put the asterisks:

```
glRasterPos2d(2,2);
glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_10, 'c');
```

but it didn't work. If I use the same two lines outside the `drawForeground` method the 'c' appears.
I already called `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` and nothing changed.

May someone help me understanding my error?

### Solution:

It turned out the solution to be disabling lighting using `glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)`, reenabling it after rendering the text.

I would like to underline that the text is rendered always at the same dimension, independently from the parameters of the `glOrtho` call.

Comment: Your call to `glOrtho()` seems odd to me. Normally, I'd think you'd want it to be `glOrtho(0, pixelWidth, 0, pixelHeight, -1, 1);`. As it is, you're saying that your world is 11 x 11 units. It's possible that the letter is being drawn off the edge of the screen, depending on whether that `(2,2)` is where the baseline, ascenders or descenders go.

Comment: @user1118321 Thank you for your comment. I thought my call to `glOrtho` behave, in this case, as an implicit scaling. However, even changing it as you suggested (and using `glRasterPos2d(width/2.0,height/2.0);`) , I am still unable to see any letter. Even scaling it up and down seems to have no effect.

Comment: Yes, that is what `glOrtho()` does - implicit scaling. It just seemed odd to try to draw an 18 point character to an 11x11 area. Other than that, what you have looks reasonable. Are there any OpenGL errors along the way?

Comment: @user1118321 Well, actually you're right saying it's odd :) for the moment I changed it to a 10 point character. However, even if it may be too big I should equally be able to see something, at least a part of the char. There are neither OpenGL errors nor warnings...

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but [according to this page](http://forum.cs175.org/index.php?topic=376.0), you need to disable GL_TEXTURE_2D to get the text to render. No idea why.

Comment: @user1118321 Oh yes, sorry, I forgot to say it. I already checked that page and disabled GL_TEXTURE_2D...I edit my post

Comment: If it's working outside of -drawForeground, then maybe the issue is the matrix transforms. What happens if you reset the projection matrix to identity before calling the character drawing method?

Comment: @user1118321 I followed your suggestion but calling `glLoadIdentity()` before `glRasterPos` seems to have no effect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing certain, but a couple of things to try if you haven't already:

What is the color set to before you call glutBitmapCharacter()?  If the drawing color is set to something that doesn't show up against the background, it could simply look like nothing is being drawn.

Have you tried calling glDisable(GL_TEXTURE) in addition to glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)?

Are there other things like lighting that you enable anywhere else in your code, and then don't disable before rendering the text that might affect things?  When I've run into bugs like this in the past, it seems like they are often related to something in the OpenGL state being in a state I didn't expect, often because I made some change to the state elsewhere and forgot to undo it.  I would recommend that you try systematically commenting out various OpenGL calls in your code, even if they don't seem directly related, and see if the characters ever show up.  If they do, then you'll know which state change you need to make/undo.